# Get the index of a tab

Tags: c#, winforms, tabs, indexing

I want to do something like this:

```
if (tabControl1.TabPages[0].Text == "Tab nr 1") {  }
```

Is something like this possible?

Comment: what is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
var index = tabControl1.SelectedIndex;
var tab = tabControl1.TabPages[index];
```

or simply

```
var tab = tabControl1.SelectedTab;
```

Comment: But I don't want the Selected one. I want the Text of tab nr 1 for example.

Comment: ...then please explain WHAT you actually want. It is not clear to me. Because `tabControl1.TabPages[0].Text` will give you the text of tab #1 so no problem there so far...

Comment: Oh sorry, the code I was just guessing, but it was actually right! When I tried it it didn't set off, but that's because I accidentally compared the wrong string, silly me... Well, thanks for the help anyway, I'll set your solution as the answer, as a thanks =).